# How do you create custom zuul filters in spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I want to write some of my own custom zuul filters for a spring cloud microservice i am writing.  Once i have the filter written how do I integrate it so the underlying netflix zuul framework can take advantage of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a `@Bean` that extends `ZuulFilter`.  See java configuration examples [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulConfiguration.java#L78).  As long as the bean is in the same context as the `@EnableZuulProxy` app, it will automatically get picked up.

```
@Bean
public MyFilter myFilter() {
    return new MyFilter();
}
```

See examples of filters [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/pre).

```
public class MyFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    //...
}
```

There are three types of filters: pre, route and post and each set of filters is executed in that order (ie all pre's first, routes 2nd and post's 3rd).

Comment: thank you for the answer. what will be the most correct and reliable way to add a filter based on the requesting origin? ie: I want to filter the request only coming from a certain origin and route it to the service, but for other origins I want to return an error code.

Comment: You have access to the request in your filters, you can use it to do as you want.

Comment: Isn't there 4 different filter types? pre, route, post and error?

Comment: yes, error is a type as well. see https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/How-it-Works#zuul-request-lifecycle for how error works.

Comment: The links in the answer are 404'ed now.