# Creating custom Zuul filters

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I want to implement custom filters for my Zuul proxy. Now, I know there has been a lot of talking about that subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467756/how-do-you-create-custom-zuul-filters-in-spring-cloud) and I took a look at the answer provided, with the examples of filters and the Spring Cloud documentation, which I went through several times. I have tried to copy some of the filters content to my use, but it didn't work.

I have a Eureka server, registering 3 separate services, one of them being the front door to the other two, collecting information from each of them and retrieving it.

What I want to be able to do is re-route the requests that Zuul receives at the beginning of the process, to redirect them through particular services, using URL parameters to determine which process should be aimed instead of another.
I already have created a filter tagged with the `@Component` annotation, implementing `ZuulFilter`. What I don't know, is how to make the redirections work, and which methods to use.

So, the question is : How can I redirect incoming requests to different registered services, using URL parameters ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [`PreDecorationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/pre/PreDecorationFilter.java#L68) for an example that matches routes based on the url path (ie `/myservice`).  If it matches a full url it sets the `routeHost` in the ribbon context, otherwise it sets `serviceId` (which would use ribbon to route).  You would need to write something similar that would match on parameter instead.

Comment: thank you. I will take a look at that right now and get back to you.

Comment: I've taken a look at the code you show on your project and I must say I don't have that much configuration, as my Zuul server is a plain Spring App with `@EnableZuulProxy`. Am I missing some kind of configuration to be able to add filters ? Or is it enough for me to create one, put a `@Bean` annotation on top of it and run the server ?

Comment: The project I showed you is the source, so of course you don't have that much configuration.  Yes, creating a filter with `@Bean` is what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you Spencer it has been very helpful, now I finally get it. Keep up the good work on Spring Cloud :)