# NetflixOSS Zuul Filter for rejecting requests

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-zuul

I am trying to use a ZuulFilter in a simple spring-cloud-Netflix Api gateway (reverse proxy) in order to authenticate requests against a custom authentication provider (via Rest call).

The Filter should reject unauthorized requests with a 401 and don't pass those requests further down to the proxied services.

Is that even possible for a ZuulFilter? I did not find documentation, example or something in Zuuls api.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got this to work, took some digging. Make sure your request isn't cached already. Just call this method from your run() method inside your ZuulFilter.

```
/**
 * Reports an error message given a response body and code.
 * 
 * @param body
 * @param code
 */
private void setFailedRequest(String body, int code) {
    log.debug("Reporting error ({}): {}", code, body);
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    ctx.setResponseStatusCode(code);
    if (ctx.getResponseBody() == null) {
        ctx.setResponseBody(body);
        ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works - one simple "ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);" was missing in our code :)

Comment: @thomas-jäckle, Assuming you call the auth-service from a pre filter, how do you get the body? What's the code?

Comment: The response body will be empty because it hasn't made a call yet (pre filter). You can actually just set ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false); to accomplish what you need likely.

Comment: Using `ctx.getResponse().sendError(code)` instead of `ctx.setResponseStatusCode(code)` and `ctx.setResponseBody(body);` allowed Spring framework to handle the error in my case.

Comment: this helped me alot i was looking for this ey

Answer (score 6):

I use a `pre` filter to check the authentication of the request, and if the request dose not authorized, then I return `401` and do not call the back end service any more. I do it in `run()` function like this:

```
RequestContext ctx = getCurrentContext();
// do something to check the authentication
if(auth failed){
  ctx.unset();
  ctx.setResponseStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
}
```

`ctx.unset()` tell the context to stop this request, and `ctx.setResponseStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());` set the http code to `401`

also see [Netflix Zuul - block request routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243381/netflix-zuul-block-request-routing/43772574#43772574)

Comment: doing ctx.unset() makes Zuul throw an exception. Just ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false); works for me.

Comment: ctx.unset() used to work with SpringBoot 1.x and the relative spring-cloud-netflix dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use authentication with the Spring Cloud then try the [Spring Security Cloud](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/) project.

Comment: Yes, that project has some useful tools for using oauth.  Zuul is basically a blank slate.  Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul has some simple routing and forwarding functionality.  Zuul filters give you access to the raw http request and response, so you can do anything you need.  See my answer to this question for getting started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055736/creating-custom-zuul-filters