# Overwrite Zuul's connection header Keep-Alive

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-websocket, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have following applications:
Gateway-Service 
Api-Service

Gateway-Serivce is Zuul proxy and Api-Service is basically rest + broker + websocket + other thechnologies.

I'm using sockjs + stomp to communicate with broker through zuul. For doing protocol upgrade socket handler need to have **connection** header set to **Upgrade**. When I request this on gateway this connection header is set to Upgrade but after the zuul processing header is set to **Keep-Alive**. 
So first question is if it's ok to replace connection header with original request header and if it's ok then how to do that? Using some Zuul filter?

Thanks

for someone interested this could be the solution...all credits goes to @spencergibb

```
@Component
public static class WebSocketHeaderFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        RequestWrapper wrapper = new RequestWrapper(ctx.getRequest());
        String upgradeHeader = wrapper.getHeader("Upgrade");
        if (null == upgradeHeader) {
            upgradeHeader = wrapper.getHeader("upgrade");
        }
        if (null != upgradeHeader && "websocket".equalsIgnoreCase(upgradeHeader)) {
            wrapper.addHeader("connection", "Upgrade");
            ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("connection", "Upgrade");
            ctx.setRequest(wrapper);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to write a zuul filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055736/creating-custom-zuul-filters

Comment: @spencergibb can you please tell me which type of filter should I use here? Pre/Post ...? Thanks

Comment: `post` won't work since it's after routing. `route` could work, but only with the right order. `pre` is where I would do it.

Comment: @spencergibb I have been trying to set the connection header as Upgrade from Pre-Filter but it doesn't work. It is always getting overridden back to Keep-Alive. Any new custom header I add, that is being passed correctly. I am using Spring Boot 2.3.7 with Zuul2. My code is identical to one posted by bilak.

Comment: This was for zuul1, there is no spring cloud support for zuul2

Comment: @spencergibb is there any alternative way to achieve the same in Zuul2 ?

Comment: I know nothing about implementing anything in zuul 2

Comment: @spencergibb  I have written the same filter in zuul gateway, but connection header is falling back to keep-alive when received at backend microservice, thus failing the handshake, any suggestion what could go wrong.

Comment: @Priyam  Did you find some solution, I am stuck with same problem.

Comment: I don't know anything about zuul 2 to help you