# Can we use HTTPMethod in Zuul Route Configuration?

Tags: netflix, netflix-zuul

The POST request to /app/login should be redirected to http://abc:100/app/login and the DELETE reqeust to /app/login should be redirect to http://xyz:200/app/login. How can this be achieved in the Netflix Zuul route configuration ? Is there an option to mention the http method in the route configuration ?

Here is the entry that explains our scenario.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    Login:
      path: /app/login
      url: http://abc:100/app/login


    Logout:
      path: /app/login
      url: http://xyz:200/app/login
```

Comment: Is there any error that you get using this configuration ?

Comment: no error, instead both the requests are getting redirected to the first URL only.

Comment: Well you are binding two different URLs to the same path, so this behaviour is not surprising.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: spring-cloud-netflix won't do this out-of-the-box with easy configuration, but it's actually easy to add a custom ZuulFilter that does what you need.  See [How do you you create custom Zuul filters in Spring Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467756/how-do-you-create-custom-zuul-filters-in-spring-cloud)

I think something like this should work for you:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        final String requestURI = 
            this.urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(ctx.getRequest());

        if ("/app/login".equals(requestURI)
            && ctx.getRequest() != null
            && !StringUtils.isBlank(ctx.getRequest().getMethod())) {

            if ("DELETE".equals(ctx.getRequest().getMethod().toUpperCase())) {
                ctx.set("serviceId", "XYZ-SVC");
                ctx.setRouteHost(null);
                ctx.addOriginResponseHeader("X-Zuul-ServiceId", location);
            } else if ("POST".equals(ctx.getRequest().getMethod().toUpperCase())) {
                ctx.set("serviceId", "ABC-SVC");
                ctx.setRouteHost(null);
                ctx.addOriginResponseHeader("X-Zuul-ServiceId", location);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you may still need a Zuul rule that maps /app/login to an existing service depending on your setup, as the bundled [PreDecorationFilter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/pre/PreDecorationFilter.java#L108) automatically sets unrecognized routes as "forward.to".

<del>I have exactly the same use case, but Zuul doesn't appear to be able to route based on HTTP method at the moment.</del>

<del>The code in question is in [ProxyRouteLocator#getMatchingRoute](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/ProxyRouteLocator.java#L132) method.  It iterates through the defined ZuulRoute entries to find matching routes.  The logic in #getMatchingRoute and the properties of ZuulRoute don't appear to match on HTTP method, unfortunately.</del>