# How to collect Metrics in Spring-Cloud Zuul

Tags: metrics, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

We have created our application with Spring-Cloud Eureka and Spring-Cloud Zuul with multiple core / support micro services registering to Eureka and accessed via Zuul, everything works fine.

We wanted to collect metrics of the APIs that is accessed via ZUUL.
For example, API - ".../extract" need to know how many times its accessed in 5,15 and 60min time period.

We did some analysis and found various metrics library like Netflix Servo, Dropwiard Metrics, Spring Boot Actuator. Everything points to implementation at the service or API level. We wanted our metrics to be captured at ZUUL itself so that a simple counter is implemented in ZUUL and that would provide us the required metrics. Any suggestion in how to implement this would be helpful.

Comment: You'd have to write your own filter. See this for a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467756/how-do-you-create-custom-zuul-filters-in-spring-cloud

Comment: Yes, I implemented the metrics based on the answer to measure transaction time.  Filters are the way to go

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I am also implementing it in filter.

Comment: You could also use a `@HandlerInterceptor`