# Format of REST API to request a service in Netflix zuul

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am trying to understand Zuul (https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) and would like to run a sample code to test it with Eureka. Using Eureka nodejs client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client) , I have registered a service on Eureka. I am not able to understand from the example app shown on github page of Zuul, how to send a REST API request to Zuul and in which format to specify the filter or even how to add my own custom filter.

Is there any sample application/code which I can look at to see the entire flow other than the one mentioned on the github page.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467756/how-do-you-create-custom-zuul-filters-in-spring-cloud) for how to create Zuul filters.

Answer (score 0):

This repo has a lot of samples for spring-cloud projects so this might be a good place to read to understand how things work  https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples

also if you haven't read this already this might help as well http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am not running on Spring cloud. I am running Zuul on Tomcat