# How to aggregate calls using zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a REST service that's deployed many times. Each instance is connected to a different Data Source. But they all have the same API and same JSON format for the data returned.

I have created a Gateway module (SpringBoot) that's also a ZuulProxy. I  then added the routIng configuratIon and It works fine; for one instance.

What I would lIke to achieve Is to make a single call to the gateway and have the aggregated data returned.

For example If I call /book on the gateway I expect all Instances of the Book Rest Service to be called, and an aggregate array of books returned.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't something the spring cloud zuul does natively. You would have to write your own filter to do it. See [How do you create custom zuul filters in spring cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467756/how-do-you-create-custom-zuul-filters-in-spring-cloud)